# How to separate the result of macro expansion into different arguments?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, boost-preprocessor

I'm writing some Boost.Preprocessor metaprogram, and I have the following problem. Consider the following macros (this is a simplification to illustrate the problem):

```
#define ITERATION_IMPL(p1, p2, p3, p4) ((p1),(p2),(p3),(p4))
#define ITERATION(args) ITERATION_IMPL(hello, args(), world)

#define ARGS() a, b
ITERATION(ARGS)
```

The preprocessed output is this:

```
((hello),(a, b),(world),())
```

This shows that `args()` is not separated into multiple arguments. According to my understanding of the standard, the arguments of the macro are fully expanded before being pasted into the replacement-list. Therefore, I would expect the following expansion sequence:

```
ITERATION(ARGS)
ITERATION_IMPL(hello, ARGS(), world)
ITERATION_IMPL(hello, a, b, world)
((hello),(a),(b),(world))
```

That is my desired result. How can I achieve it without modifying `ITERATION_IMPL` and the invocation itself?

**Edit:** If it's impossible (and I guess it is), please explain it based on any standard of C or C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if `ITERATION(ARGS)` is encountered, it takes `ITERATION_IMPL(hello, args(), world)`, replaces `args` with `ARGS`, and then rescans. `ITERATION_IMPL(hello, ARGS(), world)` is an invocation of `ITERATION_IMPL`. Therefor, it takes `((p1),(p2),(p3),(p4))`, and replaces `p2` by `ARGS()` (along with the other parameters). It then rescans and resolves to `((hello),(a, b),(world),())`. I don't know why it works that it calls a 4-parameter macro with 3 arguments in your case.

You could do

```
#define EVAL(X) X
#define ITERATION(args) ITERATION_IMPL EVAL((hello, args(), world))
```

That would take `X`, substitute `(hello, ARGS(), world)`, and then rescan, causing `ARGS()` to be replaced by `a, b`. The resulting token string `ITERATION_IMPL (hello, a, b, world)` would then do what you expected.

EDIT: Tested with GCC :)

EDIT: I noticed you want the string `((hello),(a),(b),(world))`, but my answer yields the string `ITERATION_IMPL (hello, a, b, world)`. I think that's because when it rescans after calling `ITERATION`, it replaces `IERATION_IMPL EVAL((hello, ARGS(), world))` by `ITERATION_IMPL (hello, a, b, wold)`. Then it would need another scan to notice that it can now invoke `ITERATION_IMPL` with those arguments. So `ITERATION` should be

```
#define ITERATION(args) EVAL(ITERATION_IMPL EVAL((hello, args(), world)))
```

When `X` for the outer `EVAL` is substituted by `ITERATION_IMPL EVAL((hello, args(), world))`, it rescans and yields `ITERATION_IMPL (hello, a, b, world)` for the invocation of `EVAL`. Then it rescans again for the invocation of `ITERATION` and yields the sequence you really wanted.

Comment: @ybugalobill, i think I was missing something in my answer. Updated.

Comment: @ybungalobill doesn't work with GCC and clang. And I think it makes sense to me that way. For each call to a macro, it does one rescan afterwards.

Comment: maybe. I feel like there are some dark corners in C++ I'll understand only when I write my own compiler :P